# Running a thread by toggling a flag externally (from GUI)

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am making a simple JavaFX college course project and I need a good way of dealing with threads, mainly running them while a certain flag is activated.

This is a simple sketch I came up with:

```
public class ListenerService extends Thread {

    private static ArrayList<ListenerService> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    private ToggleButton button;
    private File folder;
    private SimpleBooleanProperty active = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    ListenerService(ToggleButton button, String pathname) {
        this.button = button;
        this.folder = new File(pathname);

        button.setOnAction(event -> active.set(button.isSelected()));
        active.addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue)
                            -> {if (newValue.booleanValue()) start();});

        listeners.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(active.get())
            System.out.print(".");
    }
```

The process is as following:

1. The user dynamically creates a ToggleButton on the form. A
   ListenerService object is created, to which a button and a directory
   are assigned.
2. A listener is assigned to the button - if it's clicked - activate
       the flag. Otherwise, deactivate. The flag here is a
       SimpleBooleanProperty instance.
3. If the flag is switched on, run the thread. The thread will run
   while the flag is active. If the user toggles the button again and
   deactivates it, the condition in the while loop would fail and
   thread should stop running.

As soon as I run the program, it freezes. I tried making the flag volatile, but nothing changed. Since the flag is controlled externally (from GUI), there isn't a way to make this method synchronized.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just calling `run()` won't create a new thread. You need to create a new Thread and pass the runnable in the constructor. After that call `start()`.

Comment: @Skynet stupid mistake, my bad. Edited the question since the program still freezes.

Comment: You can't call `start()` on a running or finished thread, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--

Comment: After doing as suggested in your first comment, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

You basically create a new Thread that runs as long as the button is selected and exits when the button is not selected.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ThreadApp extends Application {    

    public class Worker implements Runnable{
        private boolean active;

        public void setActive(boolean active) {
            this.active = active;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(active)
            {
                System.out.println("Active! " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
        }
    }

    public class WorkerToggle extends ToggleButton {
        Worker worker;

        public WorkerToggle(String text) {
            super(text);
            this.worker = new Worker();

            setOnAction((event) -> {
                if(isSelected())
                {
                    worker.setActive(true);
                    Thread thread = new Thread(worker);
                    thread.setDaemon(true);
                    thread.start();
                }else
                {
                    worker.setActive(false);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane rootPane = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane);

        rootPane.setCenter(new WorkerToggle("toggle me"));

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This should work fine, but creating Threads can be expensive, so you might want to look into `ThreadPoolExecutor` if you notice some performance problems there.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaFX you have the ability to use a scheduled service to run things off the main FX thread.  Here is simple sample that might help.

```
public class JavaFXApplication3 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        PollingService service = new PollingService();
        service.setPeriod(Duration.millis(1000)); // sysout every second
        ToggleButton tb = new ToggleButton("Start Process");
        tb.setOnAction(event -> {
            System.out.println(tb.isSelected());
            if(tb.isSelected()){
                service.reset();
                service.start();
            }else {
                service.cancel();
            }
        });

        VBox vbox = new VBox(tb);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();;

    }

    private class PollingService extends ScheduledService<Void> {
        @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask() {
            return new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void call() {
                    System.out.print(".#.");
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```